# How to pass IEnumerable model to controller

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, view, controller

My model is

```
public class InvBrojeviModel
{
    public int rb { get; set; }
    public int id_ulaz_sredstava { get; set; }

    public int? inv_broj { get; set; }

    public string serijski_broj { get; set; }

    public int id_sifra { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to pass this model to controller with an ajax call

```
    var m = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Ulazna_Dokumenta/InvBrojevi_Post",
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(m),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
```

I can see the model is serialized. Serialized structure is

```
    "[{\"rb\":6477,\"id_ulaz_sredstava\":308,\"inv_broj\":6477,\"serijski_broj\":null,\"id_sifra\":29},{\"rb\":6478,\"id_ulaz_sredstava\":308,\"inv_broj\":6478,\"serijski_broj\":null,\"id_sifra\":29},{\"rb\":6479,\"id_ulaz_sredstava\":308,\"inv_broj\":6479,\"serijski_broj\":null,\"id_sifra\":29},{\"rb\":6480,\"id_ulaz_sredstava\":308,\"inv_broj\":6480,\"serijski_broj\":null,\"id_sifra\":29}]":
```

But in controller the input parameter is NULL. The controller is

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InvBrojevi_Post(IEnumerable<Magacin.Models.InvBrojeviModel> _invBrojeviModel)
    {
        return Json("test");
    }
```

The input parameter **_invBrojeviModel** is NULL. Why?

Comment: TRY :
  data: '{info:' + JSON.stringify(m) + '}'

Comment: I've tried but the input parameter is still null. :(

Comment: error: function (e)
                    {
                       
                        console.log(e);
                        console.log('Failure check');
                    }

Comment: add this in your ajax code. if you have firebug then analyse console in it. check any scripting error is there?

Comment: I've found a solution for this. I'm just removed **stringify** and left only **m**.. and it works.

Comment: Hi Lazerbrain. Please add your answer to this question and mark it as answered.This answer has helped me.Other wise I'll repost your code and  then you'll had to mark it as correct answer ;)