# Pass IEnumerable model to controller through ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view where set of Images relating to certain album will be edited to change their ***description*** and to make them ***cover photo***.

**EditImageViewModel.cs**

```
public class EditImageViewModel
{
    public int ImageId{get;set;}
    public string ImageUrl{get;set;}
    public string ImageDes{get;set;}
    public bool IsCoverPic{get;set;}
}
```

From one of the controller `ActionResult`, I return `model` to `view` as 
`return PartialView("_ImageEditView",model);`.

> `model` returned above is `List<EditImageViewModel>`

Now in the view I display it as below:

**_ImageEditView.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<EditImageViewModel>
@using(Html.BeginForm("UpdateImage","Controller",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @foreach(var image in Model)
    {
        <img src="@image.ImageUrl"/>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m=>image.ImageDes)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>image.IsCoverPic)
    }
    <button type="submit" class="update" value="Update"></button>
}
```

I have an `ajax` piece of code which calls `ActionResult` as below:

```
$('.update').on('click',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var url=$(this).closest('form').attr('action');
     var formdata=$(this).closest('form').serialize();
     $.ajax({
        url:url,
        data:formdata,
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(resp){
        },
        error:function(resp){
        }
     })
});
```

My Controller `ActionResult` goes like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateImage(List<EditImageViewModel> model)
{
    //actions to be performed
}
```

My problem here is no matter what, the `model` will always be `null` in the controller, when the post occurs. The `formdata` with have the data when checked in browser console. But it isn't get passed to controller method.

After going through few posts I learnt that it creates duplicate ids for multiple records in `List` when `foreach` is used. So I changed it to `for` loop as below:

```
@model IEnumerable<EditImageViewModel>
@using(Html.BeginForm("UpdateImage","Controller",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @for(int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++)
    {
        <img src="@Model[i].ImageUrl"/>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m[i].ImageDes)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m[i].IsCoverPic)
    }
    <button type="submit" class="update" value="Update"></button>
}
```

But still the `model` is null when received in controller. I also tried using `serializeArray` instead of `serialize`, but it did not help much. I referred few posts like **[`Post 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907947/how-to-pass-ienumerable-model-to-controller)**, **[`Post 2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299016/pass-ienumerable-list-to-controller)** etc., but none of them solved this problem.

> Ultimately, how can I pass this **list of Model** from `ajax` to
>   `controller`?

Comment: You need to make the model `IList<T>` in order to use indexing (or preferably use a custom `EditorTemplate` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for more detail). But your `RadioButtonFor()` makes no sense - did you mean `CheckBoxFor()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. Was expecting you to drop in.. ;) However, its actually a radio button, since I want only one image as cover photo, and when one of the radio button is clicked others will be set disabled is what I had on mind and preferred radio button group. Isnt that right option?

Comment: But you code will just generate a single radio button for each `EditImageViewModel` with no value attribute that would cause model binding to fail (it will submit a `null` value to a property which only accepts `true` or `false`). And since each one has a different group name, you can select all of them (but never unselect any of them)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Also, I've tried using `for` loop instead of `foreach`, which when inspected generates `id` and `name` like `[1].ImageDes`, `[2].ImageDes` etc., Isn't that quite right way to do. As far as `EditorTemplates` are considered we cannot have looping for it right?

Comment: Using a `for` loop will work fine (but I assume its really `@model List<EditImageViewModel>` in the view) and that your indexers are starting at zero - `name="[0].ImageDes"`, `name="[1].ImageDes"` etc (note also that the `id` attributes have nothing to do with model binding - all that matters is the `name` attribute)

Comment: And if you use an `EditorTemplate`, then a loop is not required - in the main view, `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)` will generate the correct html based on each item in the model (and you model can be `IEnumerable<T>` when using an `EditorTemplate`)

Comment: Exactly.. Its starts from `name=[0]...`. But still the `model` will be `null`. Would there be problem with `_form.serialize`. Was that the right option to send data? However, I will try once with editor template and let you know how it goes.. :)

Comment: `$('form').serialize();` will work fine. Based on the code you have shown, the model will not be `null` (although only the `ImageDes` property of each item will be bound)

Comment: try $('form').serializeArray();

Comment: @REDEVI_, OP has already stated he has tried `serializeArray()` - but `.serialize()` is the correct method to use anyway

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. Thanks much for your help.. With `IList` its working now.. :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. Buddy you there?

Comment: I am now. Glad you sorted it, but I hope you did not use the awful anti-mvc code in the answer you accepted.

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. No I did not use anti-mvc code.. :) But still facing some issues.. May be due to my project setup.. In test sample project its working fine for me, but not on the development project.. I dont find any other way to dig this more.. spent 2 days already..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to post a collection to the controller, you will need to add indexes to your name. Otherwise MVC does not know how to bind the model.

For example

```
@model IEnumerable<EditImageViewModel>
@using(Html.BeginForm("UpdateImage","Controller",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @for(int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++)
    {
        <img src="@Model[i].ImageUrl"/>
        <textarea name="@string.Format("ImageDes[{0}]", i)">@Model[i].imageDes</textarea>
      <input type="radio" name="@string.Format("IsCoverPic[{0}]", i)" value="@Model[i].IsCoverPic" > 

    }
    <button type="submit" class="update" value="Update"></button>
}
```

Comment: Yes.. But `model` has to be `IList` instead of `IEnumerable` and `@Html.TextAreaFor` and `@Html.RadioButtonFor` instead of above 2 `html` controls.. Please update the same..

Comment: I did not use the helper methods to make the point that an index is required :). You can still use the helper methods if you want